# How to remove function pointer from std::deque by val?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, deque, pointer-to-member

I am using `std::deque` to keep callback functions.

Everything works perfectly except removing a specific callback.

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> cb_Action;
std::deque<cb_Action> actionCallbacks;
```

I can Add items one by one or clear all of them without any problems.

But I cannot remove a specific callback from the `deque` variable.

```
actionCallbacks.erase ( std::remove(actionCallbacks.begin(), actionCallbacks.end(), callbackToRemove), actionCallbacks.end());
```

It gives compile time error:

```
binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type:'std::function<void(void)>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

So, how can I remove a specific `cb_Action`?

Comment: This is because std::function cannot be compared against each other. The only overload for == and != operator are those that compare against nullptr.

Comment: I think you should store struct which contain callback and its handler e.g. size_t id, and if you wanna remove specific callback you should provide its handler

Comment: @stryku: I think you mean "contains callback and its handle".  A "handler" (noun) is a thing which "handles" (verb) something.  A callback would be a typical way of writing a handler in C++.  A "handle" is (amongst other things) a way you can refer to an object.

Comment: @MartinBonner you got me. I've spend too much time coding on windows ;) Of course by saying handler I mean callback id or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with usual functions you can do something like this based on [std::function::target](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target):

```
void callback_1(void) {}
void callback_2(void) {}

actionCallbacks = {
    std::function<void(void)>(callback_1),
    std::function<void(void)>(callback_2),
    std::function<void(void)>(callback_1)
};

actionCallbacks.erase(
    std::remove_if(actionCallbacks.begin(), actionCallbacks.end(), [](cb_Action action) {
        return (*action.target<void(*)(void)>() == callback_1);
    }),
    actionCallbacks.end()
);
```

Here all items with `callback_1` inside are removed.

Comment: This creates the same problem. It compares `std::function<void(void)>` with another `std::function<void(void)>`. callback_1 from your example is being pushed back to actionCallbacks. So I cannot use callback_1 directly in the comparison method and when I use cb_Action, that still is not working.

Comment: @frankish I can't certainly understand what do you mean, sorry. This method compares pointers to functions in a perfectly valid way. Why can't you use `callback_1` directly?